# Clicking on the Menu item moves to the top of the page even if in the mid page in bootstrap offcanvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

when i'm Clicking on the Menu item it's moves to the top of the page(content canvas) even if in the middle of the page.

i do not want to scroll to top if i in middle of the page.

can anyone explain how to fix this issue?

```
<ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="index.php">OUR HOTEL</a></li>
         <li><a href="accommodation.php">ROOMS AND SUITES</a></li>
         <li><a href="dining.php">DINING</a></li>
         <li><a href="activities-and-services.php">ACTIVITIES AND SERVICES</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: If the links have href="#" that is what will happen.

Comment: @partypete25 do you know how to prevent it?

Comment: Well you need to update the links href. You are either linking to another page (so add the url) or to a section on the page (so add the sections id, eg #main)

Comment: @partypete25 i have already added the urls to all menu items a tag

Comment: Add your html to your question

Comment: @partypete25 i added

Comment: So for example, if you are on "our hotel" (index.php) and you click on "rooms and suites" (accommodation.php) does it load the "rooms and suites" page correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94564/discussion-between-anuruddhika-and-partypete25).